# Regex for zeroing in on build output text error

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to quickly hone in on what failed in a build log output that is nearly 5k lines long, using Notepad++ as my editor for the file. Notepad++ has the nice ability to specify regular expressions, so I am wondering if there is a way to not match:

```
Compile complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
```

but to match, for example:

```
Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
Compile complete -- 100 errors, 0 warnings
```

where the match would be (1 or more) errors.

If this isn't possible, I will probably just write a quick line-by-line parsing tool instead, but I was hoping someone on StackOverflow could whip out a regular expression in the same amount of time - I'm definitely not proficient enough with regular expressions to be able to write one for my needs in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Compile complete -- [1-9][0-9]* errors
```

Answer (score 1):

`Compile complete -- .*[^0].* errors`

seems to work for me.